# Xcode 4 - List of Tokens for use in Build Settings paths

Tags: ios, xcode4

Can anyone point me in the direction of a full list of supported tokens for use in file paths?

EG.

$(SRCROOT)

$(PROJECT_TEMP_DIR)

$(CONFIGURATION)

$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xcode Build Settings Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html)